# Returning all combinations of two columns based on a third one in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with an Oracle SQL database trying to print all possible combinations of two columns in a tables based on a third column.

To further explain. I have a table with three columns: ID, attribute1 and attribute2. Say each that for each ID, attribute1 can be equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4 and the same goes for attribute2. The ID can have more than one value of each attribute.

Currently, if ID=1 has attribute1 = 1,2 and attribute2 = 3, 4 and ID=2 has attribute1 = 1,2,3 and attribute2 = 1, 4 it might be listed as

```
ID   attribute1    attribute2
1    1             3
1    2             4
2    1             1
2    2             1
2    3             4
```

What I would like is all combinations of attribute1 and attribute2 for each ID so it would look like this:

```
ID   attribute1    attribute2
1    1             3
1    1             4
1    2             3
1    2             4
2    1             1
2    1             4
2    2             1
2    2             4
2    3             1
2    3             4
```

Comment: so are you still on `Oracle` or is it `SQL Server` now ?

Comment: Well I'm pretty new to databases but I'm using Oracle SQL developer, I think that means it's an oracle server, right?

Comment: Yes, most likely, but you've tagged the question "sql-server", which means "Microsoft SQL Server".  It should be tagged "oracle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all combinations between attribute 1 and attribute2 for each ID:

```
SELECT A1.ID, attribute1, attribute2
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, Attribute1 FROM MyTable) A1
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, Attribute2 FROM MyTable) A2 ON A1.ID = A2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I'm running this I get the error "FROM keyword not found where expected", any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to specify the 'FROM Table' inside the subqueries, now I have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.attribute1, t2.attribute2
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2
    ON  t1.id = t2.id
    AND t1.attribute1 = t2.attribute1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.id, t1.attribute1, t2.attribute2
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2
    ON  t1.id = t2.id
    AND t1.attribute2 = t2.attribute2
```

If you don't want duplicates, replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION`.

I think you could do it this way, too, which might be better but might perform worse:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.attribute1, t2.attribute2
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2
    ON  t1.id = t2.id
    AND (t1.attribute1 = t2.attribute1 OR t1.attribute2 = t2.attribute2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does this mean that I have to create a second table called t2 first?

Comment: @Tom Axelsson: t1 and t2 are aliases. Table is the same - MyTable - which you should replace with your real table name.